# Low disk space alert by percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a query which gives Server drives space, if it hits less than 25 GB. But I need on percentage Basis like if it hits less than 10% then it should alert us. I require this as we are in discussions about buying monitoring tools.

Here is the query:

```
Create Procedure dbo.DiskSpaceAlert_Surya

As
Begin

create table #DriveSpaceLeft (Drive varchar(10),
                              [MB Free] bigint)
insert #DriveSpaceLeft (Drive, [MB Free])
   EXEC master.dbo.xp_fixeddrives;

create table DrivesWithIssue (Drive varchar(10),
                              [MB Free] bigint )

insert into DrivesWithIssue 
  select Drive, [MB Free] from #DriveSpaceLeft
  where [MB Free] < 25000

drop table #DriveSpaceLeft

declare @cnt int  
select @cnt=COUNT(1) from DrivesWithIssue
if (@cnt > 0)
begin

    declare @strsubject varchar(100)
    select @strsubject='Check drive space on ' + @@SERVERNAME

    declare @tableHTML  nvarchar(max);
    set @tableHTML =
        N'<H1>Drives with less that 25 GB Free  - ' + @@SERVERNAME + '</H1>' +
        N'<table border="1">' +
        N'<tr><th>Drive</th>' +
        N'<th>MB Free</th></tr>' +
        CAST ( ( SELECT td = [Drive], '',
                        td = [MB Free]
                  FROM DrivesWithIssue
                  FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
        ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
        N'</table>' ;

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    --@from_address='test@test.com',
    @recipients='',
    @subject = @strsubject,
    @body = @tableHTML,
    @body_format = 'HTML' ,
    @profile_name='Databasemail'
end

drop table DrivesWithIssue
End
```

And the result is

[image]

I need another column as percentage Free.

Please feel free to share if you have any other scripts to fulfill this requirement.

Comment: Have you considered Zabbix? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zabbix

Comment: I am looking within sql not any monitoring tools

Comment: In order to calculate percentage free, you need to know the total space (size) of the drive. If that's not in your information, you can't calculate a percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to solve the same...

SP to get an alert if drive space is < 10

```html
USE [MYDB]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[DiskSpaceAlert_Surya]    Script Date: 3/24/2015 11:49:50 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


Create Procedure [dbo].[DiskSpaceAlert_Surya]

As
Begin
declare @cnt int 

create table #DriveSpaceLeft (Drive varchar(10), [total_space] bigint,
                              [MB_Free] bigint, [percentage_free] decimal(12,2))
insert #DriveSpaceLeft (Drive, [total_space],[MB_Free],[percentage_free])
     SELECT DISTINCT 
 --S.TOTAL_BYTES,s.available_bytes,s.logical_volume_name,*,
   s.volume_mount_point [Drive],
   CAST(s.TOTAL_BYTES / 1048576 as decimal(12,2)) [Total Space MBs],
   CAST(s.available_bytes / 1048576 as decimal(12,2)) [AvailableMBs],
   (CAST(s.available_bytes / 1048576 as decimal(12,2)) / 
   CAST(s.TOTAL_BYTES / 1048576 as decimal(12,2)) * 100) [Percentage]
  FROM 
   sys.master_files f
   CROSS APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(f.database_id, f.[file_id]) s;
  SELECT @cnt=COUNT(*) FROM #DriveSpaceLeft  WHERE percentage_free < 50
 
if (@cnt > 0)
begin
    declare @strsubject varchar(100)
 select @strsubject='Check drive space on ' + @@SERVERNAME

 declare @tableHTML  nvarchar(max);
 set @tableHTML =
     N'<H1>Drives with less than 10% Free  - ' + @@SERVERNAME + '</H1>' +
  N'<table border="1">' +
  N'<tr><th>Drive</th>' +
  N'<th>Total space</th>'+
        N'<th>MB Free</th>'+
     N'<th>Percentage (%) Free</th></tr>' +
     CAST ( ( SELECT td = [Drive], '',
                  td = [total_space], '',
      td = [MB_Free], '      ',
      td = [percentage_free]
      FROM #DriveSpaceLeft WHERE percentage_free < 50
      FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
  ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
  N'</table>' ;

 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
 @recipients='con-balususr@mail.com;',
 @subject = @strsubject,
 @body = @tableHTML,
 @body_format = 'HTML' ,
 @profile_name='Databasemail'
 
end
DROP TABLE #DriveSpaceLeft
End

GO
```

And the Result is (I have tested for below 50%)

[image]

Thanks all for your valuable Time....

Answer (score 0):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF Object_ID('tempdb..#drives', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #drives;
  END
;

CREATE TABLE #drives (
   drive              nvarchar(512)
 , drive_name         nvarchar(512)
 , available_space_mb decimal(18,4)
 , total_space_mb     decimal(18,4)
 , percentage_free As Cast((available_space_mb / total_space_mb) As decimal(5,2))
);

INSERT INTO #drives (drive, available_space_mb)
  EXEC master.dbo.xp_fixeddrives
;

; WITH drive_details AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         Left(s.volume_mount_point, 1) As drive
       , s.logical_volume_name As drive_name
       , s.total_bytes     / 1024.0 / 1024.0 As total_space_mb
       , s.available_bytes / 1024.0 / 1024.0 As available_space_mb
  FROM   sys.master_files As f
   CROSS
    APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(f.database_id, f.file_id) As s
)
UPDATE drives
SET    drive_name         = drive_details.drive_name
     , total_space_mb     = drive_details.total_space_mb
     , available_space_mb = drive_details.available_space_mb
FROM   #drives As drives
 INNER
  JOIN drive_details
    ON drive_details.drive = drives.drive
;

SELECT drive
     , drive_name
     , available_space_mb
     , total_space_mb
     , percentage_free
FROM   #drives
ORDER
    BY drive
;
```

Comment: Note that you cannot get available space for drives that do not have database files on them, but we can still report on their available space, so we might as well include them!